# @RefreshScope - JUnit testcases

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, junit4

I am trying to test my controller using JUNIT test cases but finding the below exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Scope registered for scope name 'refresh'
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:35)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.getTarget(CglibAopProxy.java:705)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655)
```

Answer (score 35):

try to put in your test file:

```
@ImportAutoConfiguration(RefreshAutoConfiguration.class)
```

Comment: Where is RefreshAutoConfiguration supposed to exist? I cannot import this class.

Comment: org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.RefreshAutoConfiguration my IntelliJ couldn't find it either

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue when I used @WebMvcTest (For test case) and @RefreshScope (For configuration)

Solution: Use

```
@SpringBootTest
```

instead of

```
@WebMvcTest
```

Reason: RefreshScope needs the complete container to work and when we use WebMvcTest it does not use the complete container. 
WebMvcTest does not load all the configurations for spring. Probably because of this the RefreshScope wasn't loaded.

Comment: Also, the other solution mentioned in this thread worked for me

Used `@ImportAutoConfiguration(RefreshAutoConfiguration.class)` by keeping `@WebMvcTest` in test

Comment: My problem was with `@RequestScope` rather than `@RefreshScope`, but this solution worked for my use case also.